# remove spaces in string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to do some functions on some text field contents before submitting the form, like checking the validity of the customer registeration code, having the customer name as his code in customers table appending an incrementing number.

I don't want to do it after the form is submitted becuase I need it to be displayed in the code field before submitting the form.

My code:

```
function getCode(){
    var temp = document.getElementById("temp").value ;
    var d = parseInt(document.getElementById("temp").value) + 1;
    document.getElementById("customernumber").value = d;
    document.getElementById("code").value = document.getElementById("name").value+"-"+ d;
}
```

It all works fine, but the last line of code developed the code WITH the spaces between the code.

Comment: Care to post example of text with spaces and how you want it to look like? Also, the "!" character means shouting. Please don't use it so often.

Answer (score 18):

A couple ways to remove spaces...

Using regex: `string.replace(/ /g,'');`

Splitting the string by spaces and combining the array with no delimiter:

`string.split(' ').join('');`

Answer (score 5):

```
var str = "ab cd ef gh   ";
str = str.replace(/\s+/g,"");
```